# Somewhat confused about a proof of surjective implies right inverse

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a question about the Proof $1$ in the link below.

There are a a few related questions on MSE. My question has to do with how they chose the selector function. At first I thought $g$ was a selector, but that wouldn't make sense. I think they did it implicitly. I'll try to fill in the details. Please, see if that makes sense.

Since $f$ is surjective, exists $x \in S$ s.t. $f(x) = y$ meaning $|f^{-1}(y)| \ge 1.$  But for a conclusion $f \circ g = I_T$ we need $|f^{-1}(y)| = 1.$ By Axiom of Choice, there's a selector $h$ on $S$ s.t.  $h(f^{-1}(y)) = x \in f^{-1}(y)$.  Thus for every $y$ there is some designated $x_y \in S.$ Define $g: T \to S$ as $g(y) = x_y$. Now suppose $y_1 = y_2$. Then $f^{-1}(y_1)  = f^{-1}(y_2)$ meaning $g(f^{-1}(y_1))  = g(f^{-1}(y_2))$ and so $g$ is a well-defined function. Thus $f \circ g(y) = f(g(y)) = f(x_y) = y$ and so $f \circ g(y) = I_T.$

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Surjection_iff_Right_Inverse

Comment: This theorem doesn’t even need integers, so a proof should not use absolute value. Remember, the identity function is just $f(x)=x$.

Comment: I would say that there aren't any details to fill in the proof by proofwiki, although you may need to read the links. You were meant to use formulation 2, so that digression about the selector is trite at best (I kind of did not read it). "But for a conclusion $f \circ g = I_T$ we need $|f^{-1}(y)| = 1$" is just nonsense.

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith    That's cardinality. Just my way of saying $f$ possibly maps more than a single element to $y$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, in the linked proof $g(y)$ is a set, but is $f$ defined from a set of sets to $T$?

Comment: If you look at the image in the link, you see a surjective function that is not injective. I think this scenario may help to ponder.

Comment: You are right. They use *some* selector function (what you call $h$) implicitly in the proof. Explicitly, $g(y):=h(f^{-1}(y))$. The selector function exists assuming Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, thanks. Perfect.